# unexpected at this time for searching all drives

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wrote the following batch file to search all drives to find my files but I get `"%d:\ was unexpected at this time."` error, My code is:

```
@echo off & setLocal EnableDELAYedeXpansion
for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  if exist %%d: (
  For /R %%d:\ %%G IN (*.zip) do Echo %%G >> zipres.txt
  ))
```

What is the problem of my code? Thanks in advance

Comment: The core problem is that `for /R` resolves the given root directory in an early stage *before* any `for` variables or delayed expanded variables are resolved; so in your code, `%%d` is not yet resolved to `c:`, `d:`, etc. when `for /R` tries to set its root directory, that is why you receive that error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the for will be able to parse it like that.May be you can try with:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set loc=%cd%
for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  if exist %%d: (
    pushd %%d:
    For /R %%G  IN (*.zip) do Echo %%G >>"%loc%\zipres.txt"
    popd
  )
)
```

or with subroutine.